# Tensions in objects other than ropes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, continuum-mechanics

Can you have tensions in objects other than strings and rope? suppose you have a piece of paper and you pull at it from both ends it becomes sort of taut similar to how a rope does, Isn't this tension? Is shear stress related to tension in anyway?

Comment: Yes, the paper will have tension.  One principal direction of stress will be in the direction you are pulling.  But there will be shear stresses on cross sections through the paper oriented at an angle to the principal direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tension is the opposite of compression.  Any time you have a transmission of a pulling force over a distance with a material object acting as the transmission medium, you have tension.

So, yes pulling on a piece of an anchored paper creates tension because it transmits a force to that anchor with the aid of the paper fibers.

As to your other question about the shear stress, it is related because it also involves transmission of a force but in the perpendicular direction.  For example pulling on a paper rod transmits the force over distance along the rod (by tension), but pushing the end of the rod sideways, transmits a force perpendicular to the rod.  Non-rigid objects such as ropes are almost incapable of transmitting such sideways forces.

Finally the meaning of the word "sideways" is related to the orientation of the cross-section of the transmitting medium.